# Lines not correctly drawn - ComboBox.DrawItem event

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I'm using the DrawItem event of a ComboBox control in VB.NET to draw a several lines and a text on each item. After the control is dropped down, the text of each item is correctly drawn but all the lines are superimposed in the first item. When I slowly scroll down to the end, the text of each item is correctly drawn but no lines are drawn. When I slowly scroll up to the start, the text of each item is correctly drawn and lines are correctly drawn. When I scroll up or down fast, the text of each item is correctly drawn but the lines are superimposed in groups. Any ideas?

Link to image showing this:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ou-lLESO_OTjJuT0ZhdHRzV1U/view?usp=sharing

```
Private Sub cbxShape_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles cbxShape.DrawItem


    e.DrawBackground()
    With figureTypeList.figureTypes(e.Index)
        Dim n_points As Integer = .vertices.Count
        For i = 0 To n_points - 2
            Dim x1 As Integer = .vertices(i).X * 3000 + e.Bounds.Width / 2
            Dim y1 As Integer = .vertices(i).Y * 3000 + e.Bounds.Height / 2
            Dim x2 As Integer = .vertices(i + 1).X * 3000 + e.Bounds.Width / 2
            Dim y2 As Integer = .vertices(i + 1).Y * 3000 + e.Bounds.Height / 2
            Dim startpoint As New System.Drawing.Point(x1, y1)
            Dim endpoint As New System.Drawing.Point(x2, y2)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(New System.Drawing.Pen(Brushes.DarkBlue, 2), startpoint, endpoint)
        Next i
    End With

    Dim size As Single = 10
    Dim myFont As System.Drawing.Font = _
        New System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, size, FontStyle.Bold)

    Dim rectangle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(2, e.Bounds.Top + 2, _
        8 * e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height - 4)

    e.Graphics.DrawString(figureTypeList.figureTypes(e.Index).name, myFont, _
                          System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, _
                          New RectangleF(e.Bounds.X + rectangle.Width, e.Bounds.Y, _
                          e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height))
    e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

Comment: this is a case where a picture would help

Comment: have you considered rendering the images and storing bitmaps to simplify things and allow you to check that the code actually draws the images correctly without the complications of the CBO?

Comment: Sure, I just included an image.

Comment: @Plutonix, I implemented a function to create the images in-memory and then assigned images to each item and it works. Thanks.